Finding the correct .bin files for CGVD28 and CGVD2013 for Transformation tool in Civil 3D
We're using a tool to transform drawn objects in Civil 3D from one coordinate system to another, that's not really a challenge the tool work.
There's an option to convert vertically the drawn objects from one vertical datum to another
We're looking to add the CGVD28 and CGVD2013 into the tool.

Anyone tried adding GEOID data into Civil 3D ?

you need to sign in here https://natural-resources.canada.ca/maps-tools-and-publications/geodetic-reference-systems/18766 to access the Geodetic reference systems files

There are direct files between CGVD28 and CGVD2013a. So you don't want the geoid models.

@mkennedy, I thought CGVD28 and CGVD2013a were Geoids. What do you mean by "direct files"?

@Pointdump They're vertical datums. The newer one can be realized with a geoid model, but Natural Resources Canada has made grid files that convert directly between the two. A geoid model converts between ellipsoidal heights and a vertical datum.

@mkennedy, thanks. I guess I need to nail down some terms and learn the difference between Datum and Geoid, which I thought were the same.

Thanks for the clarifications. So that tool that uses ellispoid instead of grid can't be of use for Canadian Vertical Datums (CGVD28 CGVD2013) ?
I noticed there's a tool called Eye4Software Hydromagic that has a Geoid Converter Utility - Wouldn't that be a venue to convert a grid to a geoid ?
Tia.

@mkennedy Any ideas on my previous msg ?

@Cyberflow It looks like the input and output are pull-downs, so it looks like one side doesn't have to be ellipsoidal heights. I've never used Civil 3D so I don't know if you can set up a custom vertical transformation or not.

@mkennedy Yes we can, it needs .bin files and modify a .json file to point to those. But i wonder if a .byn (For CGVD28 and CGVD2013a) would work
